# why my mongodb image isn't pushed to azure container registry?

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker-compose, dockerfile, azure-container-registry

My application image of my nodejs app is pushed to azure container register but my mongo image isnt it. why?

this is my docker file.

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8085
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and this is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
app:
image: rocketrcontainerregister.azurecr.io/rocketr_app:dev
build: 
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
ports:
- "8085:8085"
depends_on:
- mongo
links:
- mongo
container_name: rocketrapi
mongo:
image: mongo
ports:
- "27017:27017"
container_name: mongodb
```

Comment: because you didn't push them?

Comment: With "docker-compose push" do not upload all my images?

Comment: I do not have a dockerfile for my mongo image could it be that?

Comment: You build nothing in mongo service. You just get the image from docker hub. What you expect to push there?

Comment: @AlexBlex it all ok?  im ready to build my containers with Kubernetes?

Comment: Know thyself. I wanna tell you a little secret, being ready is just like being in love. No one needs to tell you you are in love, you just know it, through and through. If you have any errors building the containers - please ask. Theological questions are kinda offtopic.